# How to install the Marlowe Pioneers Daedalus bin in NixOS?

Tags: daedalus, nix, nixos, marlowe-pioneer-program

To enhance my education during the **Marlowe Pioneers** program (with simultaneous **Emurgo Haskell Dev Pro** course), I've been running **NixOS** as my daily driver for full immersion over the past two weeks or so (and *loving* it).

My google-foo is failing me regarding a declarative installation of the provided `daedalus-4.10.0-marlowe_pioneers-21765.bin`. While I'd prefer somehow declaring it globally in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` for now, alternative solutions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1):

the download is an installer. Running the installer will put an executable in `~/.local/bin/`.

When I ran this executable I got an error. It's expecting a file `/etc/localtime` which I don't have and seems that it isnt standard on nixos.

You can edit this script (`~/.local/bin/daedalus-marlowe_pioneers`) to work around this.
On line 9 perform the following diff.

```
- cat /etc/localtime > etc/localtime
+ echo "TZif2UTCTZif2UTC\rUTC0" > etc/localtime
```

This sets it to utc. I got this off another linux machine

I haven't done any more than launch the app. It does however now launch

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a way to install it declaritively. NixOS generations are a (re)configuration feature I'm loving.

Comment: By the way, I think you can set your timezone in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` and it will place that localtime link for you. I put `time.timeZone = "America/Phoenix";` into the config of a fresh NixOS install, and a link `localtime -> /etc/zoneinfo/America/Phoenix` is now found in `/etc`.

Comment: Given that the binary is not available from a standard repo, you cannot do this with ease afaik.
(Like you can with, say, firefox or a project on github setup for nixos).  

Cheers for the headsup on timezone